# Bash: Find and replace using Parameter Expansion

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to replace the input,

find_string: @include circle-progress(38px, 30px, #4eb630)

and output,

Output_string: @include circle-progress(38px, 30px)

using `${find_string//pattern/replacement_string}` where pattern is , `, #[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]?([A-Fa-f0-9]?([A-Fa-f0-9]?([A-Fa-f0-9])))'` that I supply.

In the code below, simply the `line` matching `pattern` is printed i.e `find_string`, when I read lines of code from a file, whereas I want the output_string to be printed.

```
pattern="@include circle-progress\(([0-9]{1,3}px, ){2}#[A-Fa-f0-9]
{3,6}\)" /*regex the matches find_string*/

replace_glob=', #[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]?([A-Fa-f0-9]?([A-
Fa-f0-9]?([A-Fa-f0-9])))' /*glob pattern in the string to be replaced*/

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]] 
   then
      echo "${line//$replace_glob/}" 
   fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: So basically your requirement is remove the part `#4eb630` from the input string right?

Comment: @Inian Yes, That is what I want, using Parameter Expansion only

Comment: You can't use parameter expansion of type `${source/orig/repl/}`, the variables `orig` and `repl` cannot be vaiables, they can just be strings. You need to use `sed` for replacement

Comment: @Inian The same concept works if I execute commands `echo "${source//$replace_glob/}" ` with just a single `source` in interactive mode. It replaces _@include circle-progress(38px, 30px, #4eb630)_ with _@include circle-progress(38px, 30px)_.

Comment: Use `awk` or `sed`; this is the type of task they were created to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern in parameter expansion is not a regular expression but follows the same rules as glob pattern matching:

- `*` : matches any character sequence
- `?` :  matches any character
- `[`..`]` : any character in set
- `[^`..`]` or `[!`..`]` : any character not in set

with shell option : `shopt -s extglob`, some more features but  less than regular expressions

- `@(`..`|`..`)` : match any once
- `?(`..`|`..`)` : match any 0 or 1 times
- `*(`..`|`..`)` : match any 0 or more times
- `!(`..`)` : matches all except

However bash supports some basic regex, following should work:

```
string='@include circle-progress(38px, 30px, #4eb630)'
pattern='@include circle-progress\([ ]*[0-9]{1,3}px,[ ]*[0-9]{1,3}px(,[ ]*#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3,6}[ ]*)\)'
[[ $string =~ $pattern ]] && echo "${string//"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4a)

```
echo $line | sed 's/\(@include circle-progress([0-9]\{1,3\}px, [0-9]\{1,3\}px\), #[a-fA-F0-9]\{3,6\})/\1)/'
```