# Script bash : Remove numbers from a file name between "-" and "_"

Tags: bash, file-rename

I need to remove a serial number in my file name which is between - and _ (the underscore should also be removed).

Original file name : `20190815-12345_table_file.rar`

Expected : `20190815-table_file.rar`

My bash code :

```
for f in ./*.rar;
do fn=`echo $f|sed 's/^-[0-9].*_$/-/g'`;
mv "$f" "$fn";
done;
```

I tried something like this because i know that my numbers are starting with "-" (so ^) are numbers ([0-9].*) and are ending with "_" (so  $) and I want to replace numbers by "-".

But with this method it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

You’re regex for sed doesn’t match the way you want: the start and end delimiters are anchors to the start and end of a line. Also, you want `[0-9]*` without the dots for any amount of digits.

Try this instead:

```
for f in ./*.rar; do
  fn="$( sed 's/-[0-9]*_/-/g' <<<"$f" )"
  mv "$f" "$fn"
done
```

In bash, you can use a parameter expansion to do the substitute without `sed`; I’ve forgotten the exact syntax, so I’ll leave it out for now and add it later. Check `man bash` for the details.

Answer (score 1):

An all Bash solution is:

```
for f in ./*.rar; do
  mv "$f" "${f/-*([0-9])_/-}"
done
```

You must have the `extglob` shell option enabled with `shopt -s extglob` for the `*()` pattern to work.

See the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942078) for more information on how the parameter expansion works.